# How to tell if a keyboard/mouse macro is triggered/running?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, macros, logitech-keyboard, lua

I have a Logitech G915 keyboard. I have a macro every 3 minutes to press a button.
**I want to know when the macro is running (triggered).**
How to tell if the macro is triggered/running?
I thought of a solution:
To change the lighting of the keyboard only with the first click of the G button (trigger button) on my keyboard. That way, there is a visual cue telling me the macro is triggered/running.Can I do that, Is it possible?

Comment: to confirm the macro is working you can open the On-Screen Keyboard and check the keystrokes in your macro are highlighting the virtual keys on your screen.

Comment: I wanted to change the lighting of the keyboard only with the first click of the G button (trigger button) on my keyboard. That way, there is a visual cue telling me the macro is triggered/running.

Comment: I am still looking for help.

Comment: How is the keyboard lighting controlled? Is it a specific software that does it?

Comment: It is the [logitech G hub software](https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/innovation/g-hub.html). So yes u got any idea? or someone who can help me?
I have disability so I need this fix in my life.

Comment: Looks like so far this isn't a feature. You can see that a Logitech representative replied to this person on reddit who was asking the same question as you. It's worth getting in touch with Logitech to see if there's anything they've done about it: https://www.reddit.com/r/logitech/comments/uu06v6/comment/i9e10bc/